# c# application will not run on any machine except box it was developed on

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, development-environment

I am new to development.  I followed step by step instructions from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/flashmapinwpf.html to host google maps in a wpf application using c#.
The program will compile and run in the IDE and also my windows environment.  The same executable files will not run on any other machine I have tested it on.
Program was compiled on windows 7 x64 using visual studio 2010.  I compiled as x86.
I have tried compiling with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.
I have tried using .NET 3.5, 3.5.1 and 4 on host machines.
I have included needed library files.
I attempted to run the executable on windows 7 x64, windows xp in virtual box and windows 7 x64 in virtual box.

Interestingly, a buddy of mine started me out on this project.  I watched him go through the same process of compiling the program.  He then sent me the project files and I was getting a strange exception that I could not get around.  After I compiled the program file the example I sent him my completed .exe and he was able to run it.  It seems that machines that have compiled the program are able to run it.

Why is this happening?

Windows 7 gives me these error details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: GoogleMapsFlashInWpf.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4c1d70c3
  Fault Module Name:    Flash.ocx
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.19.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   3fd4f4d4
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00051acc
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

After uninstalling and reinstall adobe flash I am now getting this error from windows:

> > See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
> >     (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog
> >     box.
> >     ************** Exception Text ************** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> >     (0x80040154): Class not registered
> >     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
> >     (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid&
> >     clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32
> >     context, Guid& iid)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid
> >     clsid)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String
> >     license, Guid clsid)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid
> >     clsid)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32
> >     state)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean
> >     fIgnoreVisible)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs
> >     e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnParentVisibleChanged(EventArgs
> >     e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs
> >     e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs
> >     e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> >     m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr
> >     hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
> >     lparam)
> >     ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
> >         Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- GoogleMapsFlashInWpf
> >         Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/paul/Desktop/New%20folder/GoogleMapsFlashInWpf.exe
> >     ---------------------------------------- PresentationFramework
> >         Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- WindowsBase
> >         Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- System
> >         Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- PresentationCore
> >         Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/PresentationCore/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects
> >         Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/paul/Desktop/New%20folder/AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.DLL
> >     ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
> >         Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
> >         Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- WindowsFormsIntegration
> >         Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsFormsIntegration/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- PresentationFramework.Aero
> >         Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 3.0.6920.4902 built by: NetFXw7
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero/3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
> >     ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
> >         Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
> >
> > ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for
>   this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the
>   jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The
>   application must also be compiled with
>   debugging enabled. .For example:
>   
>       
>    When JIT debugging is
>   enabled, any unhandled exception will
>   be sent to the JIT debugger registered
>   on the computer rather than be handled
>   by this dialog box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Fault Module Name:    Flash.ocx
Fault Module Version: 7.0.19.0
```

I suspect part of your problem might be right there -- this version of Flash was released some seven years ago!

Comment: I downloaded and installed the latest flash via adobe.com.  How can I manually check the version of flash installed on my boxes?

Comment: open you tube, right-click on video and you will get something like "About Adobe Flash Player Version" where version can be 7,8,9,10 etc.